# Variable shadowing in Java(Inheritance)

Tags: java

```
class A{
   final int fi = 10;
}
public class B extends A{
   int fi = 15;
   public static void main(String[] args){
       B b = new B();
       b.fi = 20;
       System.out.println(b.fi);
       System.out.println(  (  (A) b  ).fi  );
   }
}
```

In this code, the `System.out.println(  (  (A) b  ).fi  );` prints 10. My doubt is that although the reference and object are of class B, how does the cast work?

Comment: How does it work? By casting you're telling Java it's an `A`.

Comment: The object reference by b is still B. Why is a cast of the object B referring to A's field?

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic like methods - which field is referenced is determined at compile time, by looking at the type of the variable, not by looking at the actual type of the object at runtime (which is how it works for methods).